# NSDate adds one day

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have been working on an app which i integrated a stopwatch into. I got the stopwatch to work and its displaying seconds/minutes etc etc correctly.

But my problem is, I want to display the full time when the task has been completed (You completed this task in 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 4 seconds etc)

But whenever i do it, it always adds 1 day to the equation (For example it should be 0 days, 0 hours, 2 minutes and 14 seconds) But it outputs 1 days, 0 hours, 2 minutes and 14 seconds.

Code:

```
startDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"D' Days, 'H' Hours, 'm' Minutes and 's' Seconds'"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
overtext2.text = timeString;
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: Why are you taking the time interval of the timer and then adding that to 1/1/1970?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're really abusing NSDate here.

The reason you are getting the "extra" day is that you are actually printing the date and time, as if your timer was started at 00:00:00 1/1/1970. So if your timer runs for 4 hours, 30 minutes, `timerDate` will be 04:30:00 1/1/1970. If your timer was to run for 40 days, the days would run over and `timerDate` would be 00:00:00 9/2/1970, and your "days" value would be 9, not 40 as expected.

You would be better calculating the days, hours, minutes, seconds manually:

```
NSDate *startDate; // When the timer was started
NSTimeInterval timerValue = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]; // Time in seconds from startDate to now
NSInteger secs = timerValue % 60;
NSInteger mins = (timerValue % 3600) / 60;
NSInteger hours = (timerValue % 86400) / 3600;
NSInteger days = timerValue / 86400;
NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds.", days, hours, mins, secs];
```

Comment: Thanks, how would i integrate this into the code i have right now?

Comment: Well how do you store the value of the stopwatch?

Comment: startDate is the NSDate i use to store the date that the stopwatch was started

Comment: Also, just fully discovered where the problem has come from - see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used your answer and converted timerValue into a long and now it works! Thanks alot!

Comment: @downvoter - please tell me what was wrong with my answer so I can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

This will add number of seconds to 1970, and then you are converting that time to days:hours:minutes:seconds, that is never going to happen.

Alternatively you can do as :

```
NSInteger seconds=timeInterval;//timeInterval float converted to long.
NSInteger secs = seconds% 60;
NSInteger mins = (seconds% 3600) / 60;
NSInteger hours = (seconds% 86400) / 3600;
NSInteger days = seconds/ 86400;
NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds.", days, hours, mins, secs];
```

Comment: Any tips? I'm not really familiar with this NSDate stuff

Comment: Then look at the docu NSDateFormattingGuide

Comment: The first answer is vague, the second is a copy of c.cam108.

Answer (score 0):

have you heard about date time addition ..?
That used to cause problems in one of the cases which I did. So my advise to you always use NSDateComponents when you have to add or subtract dates. That is the correct way to do it.. please try it with that and see if it works..

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the documentation that is the problem

d   1..2    1   Date - Day of the month
D   1..3    345 Day of year

In your case the interval you calculated has the seconds right but the day is the first day of the year.

If you modify the code as follows to include the month you will also get a 1 (For january).

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"D' Days, 'M' Months, 'H' Hours, 'm' Minutes and 's' Seconds'"];
```